# Double comparison trick in Java

Tags: java, comparison

C++ allows you to combine two integer comparisons in one for range checking, like

```
(unsigned)X < (unsigned)Upper
```

which returns true when

```
0 <= X < Upper
```

The Java language has no unsigned type. Do you see a way to obtain the same effect, using a single comparison and not too much overhead ?

**Update**:

From a comment by @Bathsheba, the char type is unsigned 16 bits and will be fit for my purpose, as my integers are actually in the range of shorts.

The question remains open for plain `int`s.

Possibly something in the line of `(X | (Upper - 1 - X)) >= 0`, which allows a range of 30 bits.

Comment: I don't have an answer off the top of my head, but out of curiosity, is this really critical? I'm not sure that executing two compare commands, which are basic processor commands, is in any way more expensive than the cast and compare you have c++. 
Seems to me like the only reason to really want such a feature is heavy optimization and I'm not convinced the first option is better. That being said these are just speculations, I'm no expert.

Comment: Is this trick also woking with large X or large Upper (~ integerMax)?

Comment: Yes this is really critical. Conditional branches can be very costly (like 12 cycles instead of 1) because they break the pipelining in case of a branch misprediction. When this is performed inside a loop that needs to be executed 70 million times per second, it makes a difference. By the way, the cast is actually not performed and has zero cost. (Just an unsigned comparison is used).

Comment: @olsli: absolutely.

Comment: If X and Upper can fit in 16 bit quantities then node that the `char` type in Java is a 16 bit unsigned.

Comment: @Yves Can you check X=-2000000000 and Upper=4000000000, it returns true

Comment: @olsli: nope, you can't set Upper=4000000000.

Comment: @Bathsheba: in what way does it help ?

Comment: A cast to `char` might be feasible.

Comment: @Bathsheba: understood, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a datatype in Java that is able to hold the range of values that an unsigned 32-bit int can hold, then you need `long`. You can bit-mask with 32 one-bits to convert the signed int that is possibly negative to a surely-positive `long` value.

```
(x & 0xffffffffL) < upper

//             ^
//             Implicit conversion to long (of both arguments)
```

Of course the 64-bit "and" and the 64-bit comparison will take some extra time but probably less than the pipe line breaks.

Comment: I agree with this solution. I keep some hope that slightly better can be done as the positive values are in fact on 31 bits, while the negative ones are... negative.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well yes, but that one bit is the cost of your trick in C. In Java we don't have unsigned comparisons on 31/32-bit values (although if my suggestion was used by a lot of people, a JVM like HotSpot could easily detect it and replace the 64-bit operations with a 32-bit unsigned comparison operation)

Comment: No, there is no bit lost. The data must be signed, as it indeed goes negative (otherwise there would be no point checking positiveness). You also understand that the primary use of the test is to detect array overflow. We don't use arrays of one billion elements every day.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean that, as you mentioned yourself, although the positive values fit in 31 bits, you still need 32 bits for the trick (the trick works because when you interpret the bits of a 32 bits 2-s complement signed value like a 32 bits unsigned value, the formerly negative numbers are always greater than the highest positive value you could expression in the 32 bits 2-s complement signed value.)

Comment: I don't see your point. You need 32 bits to represent a signed number with magnitude up to 2^31.

Comment: I guess I didn't get your point then. Why did you mention "that slightly better can be done as the positive values are in fact on 31 bits" if you realized that it takes 32 bits?

Comment: For negative numbers, we can completely ignore the magnitude, while for positive numbers 31 bits of representation suffice. That virtually frees a bit for arithmetic manipulations and leaves hope to avoid switching to 64 bits.

Comment: Ok but I don't see how you could exploit that. All primitive numeric types in Java with the exception of the 16-bit `char` are signed, so any comparison with them would generate signed comparison assembly instruction (JL/JG/JLE/JGE on Intel x86-family) instructions.

Comment: A possible line of attack is by the use of bitwise operations, which are actually unsigned.