# Incorrect Syntax - while (3 < x < 10)

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error

What are some ways to express this? 
I know that the following is syntactically incorrect.

while (3 < x < 10)

Comment: while (x > 3 && x < 10) {  }

Comment: `IntStream.range(3 + 1, 10)`?

Comment: You should read Basic operators (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm) and While loop (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_while_loop.htm)

Comment: As you are broadly asking for ways to express this, I'll give you another one: `while (((x - 4) & 0xffffffffL) < 6)` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972446/double-comparison-trick-in-java/39974085)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you need to use "and" (&&) operator:

```
while (3 < x && x < 10)
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I have never seen the "and" operator before. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @NguenMatthew : No, if you mean some kind of "between" operator, if you need check the boundaries you have to use two comparison operators. Technically there is actually a way relying on oveflow - adding Integer.MIN_VALUE-4 and checking if the result is lower than MIN+10 but it's not very good and readable solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
while(3 < x && x < 10)
```